# Segmentation Fault on Function Return C++

Tags: c++

I am creating a cpu scheduler and I'm getting a segmentation fault once the readInput function returns. From what I've read the stack is destroyed in some way.

I've identified the line of code that causes it but I cannot figure out why.

Here is the relevant parts of the process class:

```
class Process{      //Process class deals with the values of various variables the process will take on over the course of execution on a process
public:

Process(){
    pid = startTime = endTime = initPriority = priority = timeSlice = totalCpuBurst = totalCpuTime = totalIoTime = 0;
}

void setPid(int proId){pid = proId;}

void setPriority(int bonus){priority = initPriority + bonus;}

void setProcessStart(int start){startTime = start;}

void setTimeSlice(int t){timeSlice = t;}

void setInitPriority(int nice){
    initPriority = (int)(((nice + 20)/39.0)*30 + 0.5) + 105;
}

void setNumCpuBurst(int duration){numCpuBurst.push_back(duration);}

void setNumIoBurst(int duration){numIoBurst.push_back(duration);}

private:
int pid, startTime, endTime, initPriority, priority, timeSlice, totalCpuBurst, totalCpuTime, totalIoTime;
vector<int> numCpuBurst;
vector<int>numIoBurst;
};
```

And here is the readInput function. Cin is from file indirection when running the program. The file contains 4 or more integers per line terminated by "***" at the end of the file. Currently only has 3 processes in my test file

```
void readInput(Process process[], int &processCount){           //read the input from the file until "***" is encountered
vector<int> values;
string inLine;
int n;
getline(cin, inLine);

while(inLine.compare("***")){
    stringstream stream(inLine);
    while(stream >> n){
        values.push_back(n);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< values.size(); i++){
        if(i == 0){                                               //get nice value, set pid and priority
            process[processCount].setPid(processCount);
            process[processCount].setInitPriority(values[i]);
            process[processCount].setPriority(0);
        }
        else if(i == 1){                                           //arrival time
            process[processCount].setProcessStart(values[i]);
        }
        else if(i == 2){                                           //number of cpu bursts
            process[processCount].setTotalCpuBurst(values[i]);
        }
        else if(i >= 3){
            if(i % 2 == 1){                                         //CPU burst
                process[processCount].setNumCpuBurst(values[i]);
            }
            else{                                                   //IO burst
                process[processCount].setNumIoBurst(values[i]);
            }
        }
    }
values.clear();
getline(cin, inLine);
processCount++;
}

    cout << "break on return";
    return;
}
```

"break on return" is printed and then I receive the segmentation fault

This is the block that causes a segmentation fault

```
        else if(i == 1){                                           //arrival time
            process[processCount].setProcessStart(values[i]);
        }
```

This is the main function up to this point

```
int main() {
    vector<Process> active, expired, io, finished, cpu;
    Process startUp[4];
    int processCount = 0, runningCount = 0;
    readInput(startUp, processCount);
    cout << "\nafter read";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question has received two votes to close, with the reason given being "Off topic: [request to] recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource." I have a hard time seeing any request like that. Here, have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `Process` more than 4 yet you only assign array of only 4 `Process`s

This will crash for all values more than 4

```
process[processCount].setProcessStart(values[i]);
```

Try changing to following

```
#define MAX_PROCESS  80
Process startUp[MAX_PROCESS];
```

`MAX_PROCESS` is maximum number of processes your file can have

Based on your earlier answer it appears as if 4 is your problem, but as per your commment its not so I suggest to update the question with backtrace.

Comment: The file only has 3 processes for testing. I tried what you suggested but still receive a seg fault

Comment: I suggest you go to debugger like `gdb` and run the program and once it crashes run `bt` command and post in your answer.